# Adding values of a two dimensional object - forEach?

Tags: javascript, object, key, key-value

How do I iterate and get sum of all values inside a sub object?

In the example below I want to add all `windows`.

```js
let house = {
  livingroom: { windows: 6, doors: 4 },
  bedroom: { windows: 4, doors: 2 },
  bathroom: { windows: 2, doors: 1 },
  garden: { windows: 0, doors: 2 }
}
```

I have also tried:
`Object.values(house).reduce(sum, curr => sum + curr));` 
& 
`let x += Object.values(house).forEach(sum => sum);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
Object.values(house).map(item => item.windows).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

If understand correctly, you need to iterate over the values, you can use `Object.values`:

```js
let house = {
  livingroom: { windows: 6, doors: 4 },
  bedroom: { windows: 4, doors: 2 },
  bathroom: { windows: 2, doors: 1 },
  garden: { windows: 0, doors: 2 }
}

let count = { windows: 0, doors: 0 }

for (const room of Object.values(house)) {
  count.windows += room.windows
  count.doors += room.doors
}

console.log(count)
```